# Minimum distance for a site between two towns

Tags: derivatives, optimization, mathematical-modeling

Mathematical modelling problem...

Two towns, A and B, on a straight line 12km apart. I want to put a site on the straight line between the two towns. From the site, travel to A is three times as often as travel to B. I want to position the site so that the amount of travel from the site to the towns is minimized.
Assumptions I have given the model are

(i) The towns and the site can be represented by points.
(ii)    The land is flat.
(iii)   The mode of transport for the run can travel in straight lines.
(iv)    The mode of transport is full for each run
(v) The run will take three times as often to A as it will to B from the site.
(vi)    We can sum the journey to both towns to get the total.

All I have is $3x + (12-x)$

I understand that the site needs to very close to A (thanks to comments and answer given already) but for this problem I require an expression in $x$ that I can differentiate, letting $\frac d{dx}=0$ and solving for $x$ and then show that it is a maximized such that the second derivative $>0$

Any solution or help with this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you squaring $x$?

Comment: Because to get a derivative it couldn't just be x? Not sure why tbh

Comment: Think about it: one round trip to $A$ and one round trip to $B$ is 24 km no matter what. So all you need to do is to minimize distance for trips to $A$, i.e. locate site as close to $A$ as possible..

Comment: When you say the run will take three times as often to A as it wil be to B from the site, do you by any change mean the time taken at all?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan time isn't a factor as far as the question goes it's amount of travel

Comment: @Vasya yes, that makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

We can assume the site is on the line segment $AB$.

Let $x$ be the distance of the site from $A$, where $0 \le x \le 12$.

The total distance traveled is given by $d=(3n)x + n(12-x)$, where $3n,n$ are the (constant) number of trips to $A,B$, respectively.

Then $d = (2n)x + 12n$, hence for $x \in [0,12]$, the minimum is achieved at $x=0\;$(i.e., place the site at $A$).

Comment: It's not in the question but I think that I have to assume that the mode of transport is full for every journey, when n isn't a factor then. Your solution makes sense to me but placing the site at A would mean a travel of 12km the B everytime..

Comment: Yes, but the savings is the zero distance to $A$ for $75$% of the trips. Take the simple case of $4$ trips, $3$ to $A$, and $1$ to $B$.

Comment: Ahhh.. I get it, minimum distance is 24km so placing the site at A makes it to B and back in 24km. THAT simple? Brilliant!